# Processor Word Problem

Tags: contest-math, word-problem

It takes 12 processor 5 min to calculate 6 solutions. If 40 processor are in two groups, where grou 1 has 4 more processors than the 2nd group, how long will it take the 2nd group to calculate 27 solutions

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: You have this tagged as contest math.  If it is a current (on-going) contest, you should not get answers for it.  If it is an older contest, please cite what contest and when it was.

Comment: Technically speaking, usually the number of solutions is **not** directly proportional to the number of processors! That's the case in real life. But perhaps in this problem you're supposed to assume so.

Answer (score 0):

If $12$ processors can compute $6$ solutions in $5$ minutes, then $2$ processors can compute $1$ solution in $5$ minutes, and so $1$ processor can compute $1$ solution in $10$ minutes. Now, we need to find the number of processors in the two groups, say $p_f$ and $p_s$ for the first and second groups, respectively. We have that $p_f+p_s=40$ and $p_f-p_s=4$. Solving for the two variables, we get that $p_f=22$ and $p_s=18$. That means that the second group, the group that we will work with for this problem, has $18$ processors. If $1$ processor can compute $1$ solution in $10$ minutes, then $18$ processors can compute $18$ solutions in $10$ minutes. We need $27$ solutions, not $18$, so we multiply the time spent computing by $\frac{27}{18}=\frac{3}{2}$ to give $10\cdot\frac{3}{2}=15$. Thus, the second group of processors can compute $27$ solutions in $\boxed{15}$ minutes.